# How to show keyboard when TextField is attached?

Tags: swiftui

I have a button and TextField on the keyboards Toolbar. So when keyboard is launched it shows. I want to call up that keyboard when action performed, i.e. button tap. As keyboards only show when TextField is active (focused), how to make the TextField inside the `ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard)` show if it's not visible until keyboard shows in the first place?

```swift
ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
    HStack{
        Button(...)
        TextField("", text: $bindingText)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I know what you want to do (σ ﾟ∀ ﾟ)

Effect:
[image: Effect]

But this goes against the original design intention of SwiftUI, so the code is very very very not elegant, but it can still be used if you can accept it. Of course, if you want to make the code more elegant, you can use a customized `Keyboar ToolbarItem` outside the keyboard, or use `UIKit` to create a more perfect invisible keyboard.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var text = ""
  @State private var items: [String] = []
  @FocusState private var isHiddenTextFieldFocused: Bool
  @FocusState private var isTextFieldFocused: Bool
  
  @State private var dummyText: String = ""
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button("Show Keyboard") {
        isHiddenTextFieldFocused = true
      }
      
      List(items, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item)
      }
    }
    .background {
      TextField("", text: $dummyText)
        .focused($isHiddenTextFieldFocused)
        .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
        .opacity(0)
        .onChange(of: isTextFieldFocused) {
          if !isTextFieldFocused {
            isHiddenTextFieldFocused = false
          }
        }
    }
    .toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
        HStack {
          Button("Done") {
            items.append(text)
            text = ""
          }
          TextField("item name", text: $text)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .focused($isTextFieldFocused)
            .onSubmit {
              items.append(text)
              text = ""
              isTextFieldFocused = false
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
          isTextFieldFocused = true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer but I want to avoid the extra TextField in the view.

Comment: I may know what you want and change the answer

Comment: Hidden Textfield it is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just too add to accepted answer by @Jiarui Wu as iOS17 has reported known bugs where toolbar not always showing on keyboard. Need to present a view before it works.

```
@State var isShowingAWorkAround = true

  ...


.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingAWorkAround) {
                Text("")
                    .presentationBackground(.clear)
                    .presentationDetents([.medium])
                    .onAppear {
                        isShowingAWorkAround = false
                    }
            }
```

solution given (adapted above from) here https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/736040